# How to get past a window prompt while calling a subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, subprocess, output

I have a jar file that I want to run in the command line and collect it's stdout with a python script.

I make the call as a subprocess like:

```py
def get_output():
  process = subprocess.run(['java', '-jar', 'myjar.jar', 'myfileargument'])
```

But a warning prompt comes up that I am unable to disable, which pauses execution until a user clicks 'OK' or presses enter. Is there a way to essentially 'click ok' in the prompt window that comes up via code and let the python script continue?

Comment: if this OK is in GUI then you can't click it because `subprocess` can uses only text streams to communicate with process. You would have to use tools like `PyAutoGUI`, `pynput` to control mouse/keyboard and click it or send ENTER. But may need more work to detect button position or set focus on GUI window.

Comment: better you should show warning and then we can see if we can disable it.

Comment: unfortunately no dice on access to the java code. will take a look at the modules you suggested and see if I can spin something up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no way for you, only using environment variables and parameters to the subprocess, to disable that warning, there is no easy way to do it.

Either you will have to go the road of UI automation, as mentionned by @furas in the comments. It may be relatively easy to do so given the multiple tools/frameworks there is to do that.

Or you may "patch" the `jar` to not require this warning. If you can replace the annoying `.class` file by another which will not require to accept the warning, it may be somewhat efficient. Or else you could install a custom ClassLoader in the java program, but it may prove to be difficult.

Comment: yeah no dice on patching the jar, don't have access to the source code and won't be able to get it. I'll probably try something along the lines of what @furas suggested and see what I can spin up.  thanks for the input!